# Plotting values in matrix corresponding to the index in an array with Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this array and matrix:

```
 delta_Array = np.array([0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06,0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10])
 theta_Matrix = 
 [[ 0.42860551  0.15916832 -0.11548373  0.21118448 -0.11248666 -0.10941028
    0.21753078  0.0066507 ]
  [ 0.42860033  0.15916739 -0.11548099  0.2111825  -0.11248553 -0.10940605
    0.21752721  0.00665198]
  [ 0.42859169  0.15916584 -0.11547644  0.2111792  -0.11248364 -0.109399
    0.21752126  0.00665412]
  [ 0.4285796   0.15916367 -0.11547007  0.21117458 -0.11248099 -0.10938913
    0.21751293  0.00665711]
  [ 0.42856405  0.15916088 -0.11546187  0.21116863 -0.11247759 -0.10937644
    0.21750223  0.00666096]
  [ 0.42854505  0.15915746 -0.11545186  0.21116137 -0.11247344 -0.10936093
    0.21748915  0.00666566]
  [ 0.4285226   0.15915343 -0.11544002  0.21115279 -0.11246853 -0.1093426
    0.2174737   0.00667121]
  [ 0.4284967   0.15914878 -0.11542637  0.21114289 -0.11246286 -0.10932146
    0.21745587  0.00667762]
  [ 0.42846735  0.15914351 -0.1154109   0.21113166 -0.11245644 -0.1092975
    0.21743567  0.00668487]
  [ 0.42843455  0.15913762 -0.11539361  0.21111912 -0.11244926 -0.10927074
    0.2174131   0.00669298]]
```

Each column of the theta_matrix is 1 color. Each element of delta_array gives the corresponding row in the theta_matrix. I realize that in order to get thse curves Im gonna need many more delta values. But for now Im just using a small input

[image]

However, this code of mine

```
  figure(1)
  plot(delta_Array, theta_Matrix)
  plt.show()
```

plots the figure like this:
[image]

Clearly Im missing many pieces. I learnt this basic stuff from here:

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/3/3f/Plot-python.pdf

But Im trying to fill in the missing pieces. Can anyone give me a hand?
Im a newbie so if you know of some simple tutorials I would appreciate it. Unfortunately most tutorials online assume a higher level of proficiency than I have.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. `theta_plots` is defined but never used. `theta_Matrix` is undefined, but I assume it should be `ThetaMatrix `. I also believe the shapes of your data is all messed up. If I look at each column of the matrix, each value is nearly a constant: For example the first column is almost always 0.428... Can you clarify a little better what you are hoping to learn to do with matplotlib here?

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback. Yes theta_plots was redundant and Ive corrected theta_Matrix typos. The 1st column values change but the maginitude is very small see the last 3 or 4 digits after decimal they change. theta_Matrix is 10x8 in dimensions and delta is 1x10 in dimension. Thus the ith row of theta_Matrix corresponds to the output values for delta_Array[i]

Comment: Right, so the data is almost constant, (but slightly different) and the plot you created shows plots of data with almost constant values... You can't see the small changes because the scale of your y-axis is too large. If you zoom in on one of the lines you will see the slight change in values.

Comment: Any suggestions how set axis such that I can zoom in?

Comment: Interactively: You Figure has a Zoom feature. Try using that button on the toolbar with the magnifying glass. 
Programmatically: Try using the `axis` function, for example to zoom in a bit on the blue line: `axis((0.009,0.100,0.006,0.007))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and data is not clear, however, try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta_Array = np.array([0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04, 0.05,
                        0.06,0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10])
#Initialized to 0s. Actual values will be appended to matrix by function
theta_Matrix = np.random.random() * np.random.rand(delta_Array.size, 8) 

fig = plt.figure()
p1 = plt.plot(delta_Array, theta_Matrix)
# make a legend for both plots
leg = plt.legend(p1, '', loc=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have update your matrix, the problem lies in the length and organization of your data.

first change the length of your x-data:

```
delta_Array = np.array([0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04, 0.05,
                        0.06,0.07, 0.08])
```

then Transpose your Matrix:

```
p1 = plt.plot(delta_Array, ThetaMatrix.T)
```

[image: data plot]

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. However, the delta values can vary so I cannot limit them. Because a delta is my x value. So I can have infinte number of x values (inputs) for my function. For each x(input) I get a vector of 8 values which are my thetas which I need to plot. Transposing the theta matrix gave me an error: "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"